# Maintaining Data across machines in the Cloud

Tags: c#, cloud, persistence

I'm working on a Cloud-Hosted ZipFile creation service.

This is a Cross-Origin WebApi2 service used to provide ZipFiles from a file system that cannot host any server side code.

The basic operation goes like this:

- User makes a POST request with a `string[]` of Urls that correlate to file locations
- WebApi reads the array into memory, and creates a ticket number
- WebApi returns the ticket number to the user
- AJAX callback then redirects the user to a web address with the ticket number appended, which returns the zip file in the `HttpResponseMessage`

In order to handle the ticket system, my design approach was to set up a Global Dictionary that paired a randomly generated 10 digit number to a `List<String>` value, and the dictionary was paired to a `Queue` storing 10,000 entries at a time. ([Reference here][1])

*This is partially due to the fact that WebApi does not support Cache*

When I make my AJAX call locally, it works 100% of the time. When I make the call remotely, it works about 20% of the time.

When it fails, this is the error I get:

`The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Meaning, the ticket number was not found in the Global Dictionary Object.

**We (with the help of Stack) tracked down the issue to multiple servers in the Cloud.**

In this case, there are three.

That doesn't mean there is a one-in-three chance of this working, what seems to be going on is this:

- Calls made while the browser is on the cloud site work 100% of the time because the same machine handles the whole operation end-to-end
- Calls made from other sites work far less often because there is no continuity between the machine who takes the AJAX call, and the machine who takes the subsequent REDIRECT to the website to download the file. It's simple luck of the draw if the same machine handles both.

Now, I'm sure we could create a database to handle requests, but that seems like a lot more work to maintain state among these machines.

Is there any non-database way for these machines to maintain the same `Dictionary` across all sessions that doesn't involve setting up a fourth machine just to handle queue?

Answer (score 1):

Is the reason for the dictionary simply to have a queue of operations?

It seems you either need:

1. A third machine that hosts the queue (despite your objection). If you're using Azure, an obvious choice might be the distributed Azure Cache Service.
2. To forget about the dictionary and just have the server package and deliver the requested result, perhaps in an asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET web app uses session state, you will need to configure an external session state provider (either the Redis Cache Service or a SQL Server session state provider).

There's a step-by-step guide [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/).